# Understanding tc qdisc and iperf

Tags: tc

I'm trying to limit bandwidth with `tc` and check the results with `iperf`. I started like this:

```
# iperf -c 192.168.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.2.1, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 23.5 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.2.7 port 35213 connected with 192.168.2.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   830 MBytes   696 Mbits/sec
```

The two instances are directly connected with through Ethernet.

I then set up a `htb` `qdisc` with one default class to limit bandwidth to 1mbit/sec:

```
# tc qdisc add dev bond0 root handle 1: htb default 12
# tc class add dev bond0 parent 1: classid 1:12 htb rate 1mbit
```

But I don't get what I expect:

```
# iperf -c 192.168.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.2.1, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 23.5 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.2.7 port 35217 connected with 192.168.2.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-12.8 sec   768 KBytes   491 Kbits/sec
```

If I double the rate, the measured bandwidth does not change. What am I missing? Why doesn't the the measured bandwidth correspond to the 1mbit from the `rate` parameter? What parameters do I need to set to limit the bandwidth to an exact given rate?

However, the `man` page says that `tbf` should be the `qdisc` of choice for this task:

> The Token Bucket Filter is suited for slowing traffic down to a precisely configured rate. Scales well to large bandwidths.

`tbf` requires parameters `rate`, `burst` and (`limit`| `latency`). So I tried the following without understanding how `burst` and (`limit`| `latency`) affect the available bandwidth:

```
# tc qdisc add dev bond0 root tbf rate 1mbit limit 10k burst 10k
```

This got me a measured bandwidth of 113 Kbits/sec. Playing around with those parameters didn't change that much until I noticed that adding a value for `mtu` changes things drastically:

```
# tc qdisc add dev bond0 root tbf rate 1mbit limit 10k burst 10k mtu 5000
```

resulted in a measured bandwidth of 1.00 Mbits/sec.

What parameters would I need to set to limit the bandwidth to an exact given rate?

Should I use the `htb` or `tbf` queueing discipline for this?

**EDIT**:

Based on these resources, I have made some tests:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinkAggregation
- /usr/share/doc/ifenslave-2.6/README.Debian.gz http://lartc.org/

I have tried the following setups.

### On a Physical Machine

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0
```

Measurement with `iperf`:

```
# tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12
# tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:12 htb rate 1mbit
# iperf -c 192.168.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.2.1, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 23.5 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.2.4 port 51804 connected with 192.168.2.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-11.9 sec  1.62 MBytes  1.14 Mbits/sec
```

Whereas the `iperf` server calculated a different bandwidth:

```
[  4] local 192.168.2.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.2.4 port 51804
[  4]  0.0-13.7 sec  1.62 MBytes   993 Kbits/sec
```

### On a Virtual Machine without Bonding

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Measurement with `iperf`:

```
# tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12
# tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:12 htb rate 1mbit
# iperf -c 192.168.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.2.1, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 23.5 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.2.7 port 34347 connected with 192.168.2.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-11.3 sec  1.62 MBytes  1.21 Mbits/sec
```

Whereas the `iperf` server calculated a different bandwidth:

```
[  4] local 192.168.2.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.2.7 port 34347
[  4]  0.0-14.0 sec  1.62 MBytes   972 Kbits/sec
```

### On a Virtual Machine with Bonding (tc configured on eth0)

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-bond0 eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    bond-primary eth0 eth1

auto eth1
allow-bond0 eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    bond-primary eth0 eth1

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
    bond-slaves none
    bond-mode 1
#    bond-arp-interval 250
#    bond-arp-ip-target 192.168.2.1
#    bond-arp-validate 3
```

Measurement with `iperf`:

```
# tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 12
# tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:12 htb rate 1mbit
# iperf -c 192.168.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.2.1, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 23.5 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.2.9 port 49054 connected with 192.168.2.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-11.9 sec  1.62 MBytes  1.14 Mbits/sec
```

Whereas the `iperf` server calculated a different bandwidth:

```
[  4] local 192.168.2.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.2.9 port 49054
[  4]  0.0-14.0 sec  1.62 MBytes   972 Kbits/sec
```

### On a Virtual Machine with Bonding (tc configured on bond0)

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-bond0 eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    bond-primary eth0 eth1

auto eth1
allow-bond0 eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    bond-primary eth0 eth1

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
    bond-slaves none
    bond-mode 1
#    bond-arp-interval 250
#    bond-arp-ip-target 192.168.2.1
#    bond-arp-validate 3
```

Measurement with `iperf`:

```
# tc qdisc add dev bond0 root handle 1: htb default 12
# tc class add dev bond0 parent 1: classid 1:12 htb rate 1mbit
# iperf -c 192.168.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.2.1, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 23.5 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.2.9 port 49055 connected with 192.168.2.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-13.3 sec   768 KBytes   475 Kbits/sec
```

Whereas the `iperf` server calculated a different bandwidth:

```
[  4] local 192.168.2.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.2.9 port 49055
[  4]  0.0-14.1 sec   768 KBytes   446 Kbits/sec
```

The result does not change if I remove `eth1` (the passive interface) from the bond.

## Conclusion

*Traffic Control* on a bond interface does not work, or at least not as expected. I will have to investigate further.

As a workaround one could add the *queueing disciplines* directly to the interfaces belonging to the bond.

Comment: Strangely enough, this seems to have worked for this guy: http://blog.tinola.com/?e=22

Comment: I think with htb, you have to use `tc filter` to put the packets into classes. You may also need to change some of the htb parameters (tune it just like tbf). I suggest looking into `tcng`, which is a front-end to tc. (These are quick pointers...)

Comment: I did not see any filters in your post. What commands are you using to match the traffic so that it can be rate limited?

Answer (score 2):

When you are unsure about how tc works you can still monitor tc and look how the packets flow? You can use my script to monitor tc and need to run it in a terminal with lifted privilege. You can change wlan0 to another interface and you also need grep and awk:

```
      #!/bin/sh
      INTERVAL=15
      while sleep $INTERVAL
      do
             /usr/sbin/tc -s -d class show dev wlan0

             uptime
             more /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree | grep -v grep
             echo cache-name num-active-objs total-objs obj-size
             SKBUFF=`more /proc/slabinfo | grep skbuff | grep -v grep | awk 
             '{print $2} {print $3} {print $4}'`

             echo skbuff_head_cache: $SKBUFF
      done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the `burst`/`limit` values. The *token bucket* algorithms scale well, but have a limited accuracy/speed ratio.

Accuracy is achieved by using a small bucket, speed by increasing the size of the tokens. Large tokens mean the rate at which they are replenished is decreased (tokens per second = bytes per second / bytes per token).

The `rate` parameter gives the *average* rate that is not to be exceeded, the `burst` or `limit` parameters give the size of the averaging window. As sending out a packet at line speed exceeds the set rate for the time where the packet is transferred, the averaging window needs to be at least large enough that sending a single packet does not push the entire window over the limit; if more packets fit in the window, the algorithm will have a better chance of hitting the target exactly.

Answer (score 0):

run this before add queue discipline on bonding interface (bond0 in this case)

```
ipconfig bond0 txqueuelen 1000
```

it not work because software virtual device like bonding interface has no default queue.

Answer (score 0):

Since `bond` devices doesn't have defined queue, setting the `qdisc` size explicitly fixes the issue for me.

Here is an example for a leaf `qdisc` to be used under `HTB` structure :
`tc qdisc add dev $dev parent $parent handle $handle pfifo limit 1000`